# Javafx Binding throw exception in application start() method

Tags: javafx, binding, tableview, invocationtargetexception, unsupportedoperation

`UnsupportedOperationException` thrown in `Bindings.bindContent()` when bind the objects to `TableView`. Why? How to resolve this problem?

I am using java 8 update181.

```
 Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374)
    at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:571)
    at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ContentBinding.bind(ContentBinding.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.binding.Bindings.bindContent(Bindings.java:1020)
    at problem_bind.Main.start(Main.java:42)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more Exception running application problem_bind.Main
```

My codes:

```
package problem_bind;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {
        House house = new House();

        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn = createColumn("First Name", "firstName");
        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn = createColumn("Last Name", "lastName");
        table.getColumns().add(firstNameColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(lastNameColumn);

        ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        data.addAll(house.getPersons());
        table.setItems(data);
        Bindings.bindContent(house.getPersons(), table.getItems());

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, null, null, null, null);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private TableColumn<Person, String> createColumn(String title, String property) {
        TableColumn<Person, String> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setSortable(false);
        col.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>(property));
        col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        return col ;
    }

    public static class House {
        private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

        public House() {
            this.persons = Arrays.asList(
                    new Person("Jacob", "Smith", this),
                    new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", this),
                    new Person("Ethan", "Williams", this),
                    new Person("Emma", "Jones", this),
                    new Person("Michael", "Brown", this));
        }

        public List<Person> getPersons() {
            return persons;
        }
    }

    public static class Person {
       private String firstName ;
       private String lastName ;
       private House house;

       public Person(String firstName, String lastName, House house) {
           this.firstName = firstName ;
           this.lastName = lastName ;
           this.house = house;
       }

       public String getFirstName() {
           return firstName;
       }

       public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
           this.firstName = firstName;
       }

       public String getLastName() {
           return lastName;
       }

       public void setLastName(String lastName) {
           this.lastName = lastName;
        }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your use of [`Arrays.asList(Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)). That method:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

Because of this, the returned `List` does not support operations such as `add` or `remove`. Instead, you'd modify such a list through the `set` method. The former two methods inherently require a variable-sized list. The implementation of `Bindings.bindContent` apparently tries to use those unsupported methods when synchronizing the lists.

Change this:

```
this.persons = Arrays.asList(
        new Person("Jacob", "Smith", this),
        new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", this),
        new Person("Ethan", "Williams", this),
        new Person("Emma", "Jones", this),
        new Person("Michael", "Brown", this));
```

To this:

```
persons = new ArrayList<>();
persons.add(new Person("Jacob", "Smith", this));
persons.add(new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", this));
persons.add(new Person("Ethan", "Williams", this));
persons.add(new Person("Emma", "Jones", this));
persons.add(new Person("Michael", "Brown", this));
```

*Note: In your current code, prefixing with `this` is unnecessary. But you can still use it if you prefer.*

*Note #2: See [@Pagbo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55133433/javafx-binding-throw-exception-in-application-start-method/55133982?noredirect=1#comment97014857_55133982).*

Basically, make sure you use a `List` which supports the `add` and `remove` operations.

---

You may be wondering why calling [`Bindings.bindContent(List,ObservableList)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#bindContent(java.util.List,javafx.collections.ObservableList)) is leading to a `remove` call in the first place. This is because that method returns:

> A content binding [ensuring] that the `List` contains the same elements as the `ObservableList`. If the content of the `ObservableList` changes, the `List` will be updated automatically.

In other words, the `List` is updated to match the `ObservableList`. This involves, when first creating the binding, clearing the `List` then adding all the elements of the `ObservableList` to it.

Comment: Note : unnecessary to re-instatiate the `ArrayList` in the `House` constructor as it is already done in the attribute declaration.